# Can't reach azure virtual machine with RDP Connection

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, remote-access, rdp, connect

I've created a new Windows (Windows Server 2022 Datacenter Azure Edition) VM into Microsoft Azure, but I can't conntect with RDP.

The checks I've done are the followings:

1. Enable the 3389 port in the Network Settings from ANY IP

[image]

2. Check the company firewall if it blocks outgoing connections on the 3389 port but it doesen't (We have VM's on Oracle cloud too and we can connect easily with RDP on the public IP.
3. It doesen't answer pings and telnets
4. I used the Redeploy under VM > Help > Redeploy + Reapply
5. Tried connecting using a network outside my company, but no answer neither.
6. Under Boot diagnosis I can see the "Screenshot"
7. Under VM > Connect > Connect I've tried the "Check access" button and after 10 seconds more or less it says "Accessible"

Am I missing something?

I'm expecting it to connect via RDP Connection.

Comment: By "Enabling the 3389 port in the Network Settings from ANY IP" do you mean you created a NSG Inbound to allow 3389 from ANY IP? Can you please share the NSG screenshot in your question?

Comment: Hi, I've added it. The one with the censored IP is the one with our firm IP. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you addressed this article and steps? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshoot-rdp-connection

Comment: Follow this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/connect-rdp) to rdp into your windows VM
I have similar windows OS setup as [yours](https://i.imgur.com/sl9O4EW.png). Here multiple methods are there to login, I will choose the native method and download the rdp file and place it in location of my choice (I placed it on my [desktop](https://i.imgur.com/Q4oPHiJ.png)) and I am able to [connect](https://i.imgur.com/E5Z6InF.png). [here](https://i.imgur.com/zDWwwo7.png)

Comment: References:

-   [Troubleshoot Remote Desktop connections to an Azure virtual machine - Troubleshoot using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshoot-rdp-connection#troubleshoot-using-the-azure-portal)
-   [Troubleshoot Remote Desktop connections to an Azure virtual machine - Troubleshoot VMs created using the Classic deployment model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshoot-rdp-connection#troubleshoot-vms-created-using-the-classic-deployment-model)

Comment: [- Connect to a windows vm using ssh/rdp | look on the left column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/bastion-connect-vm-ssh-windows)

Comment: Since yours is particularly a troubleshooting based question, would suggest yoy to consider these additional checks: [RDP Configuration Reset](https://i.imgur.com/1dISeU8.png) , [Use the "IP flow verify" feature in the Azure portal to check if NSG rules are incorrectly blocking RDP traffic. Ensure there's a prioritized inbound "Allow" rule for port 3389.](https://i.imgur.com/Mc1lljc.png) , check the [Console Log](https://i.imgur.com/eyZnpfw.png)

Comment: Any specific error message you are getting? Can you share it? are you using public or private IP ?

Comment: Hello everyone, after troubleshooting it with my PM, we discovered that someone added a rule in the Virtual Network > Subnets > Route Table that was denying our RDP connection to the VM's. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: @RaresGheorghe can you please show the steps you took and where you did go as an answer for future reference for others?

Answer (score 0):

If you’re facing RDP connectivity issues with your Azure VM despite standard troubleshooting, consider these additional steps:

1. **RDP Configuration Reset**: In the Azure portal, navigate to your VM, go to Reset password under Support + troubleshooting selects Reset configuration only,” and hit “Update.”
   [image]
2. **Route Table Rules**: Check if any route table is blocking your RDP connection traffic, navigate to
   **Virtual Network > Subnets > Route Table**

[image]

3. **NSG Rule Verification**: Use the “IP flow verify” feature in the Azure portal to check if NSG rules are incorrectly blocking RDP traffic. Ensure there’s a prioritized inbound “Allow” rule for port 3389.
   [image]
4. **Console Log Inspection**: Examine the VM’s console logs via boot diagnostics to identify potential OS-level issues affecting RDP connectivity.
   [image]
5. **NIC Reset**: Resetting the VM’s NIC through the Azure portal or Azure PowerShell can help resolve underlying network issues.
6. **Resource Health Check**: Under the VM’s “Resource health” in the Azure portal, verify there are no platform-related issues impacting your VM.

Follow this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/connect-rdp) to rdp into your windows VM

Here I have similar windows OS setup , I have even kept the NSG same as yours to “Any”
[image]

and using the above shared MS document I am able to RDP into the machine as below-

[image]

Here multiple methods are there to login, I will choose the native method and download the rdp file and place it in location of my choice (I placed it on my desktop)
[image]

key in the creds which you chose during setup
[image]
[image]

and you’re in
[image]

**References:**

- [Troubleshoot Remote Desktop connections to an Azure virtual machine - Troubleshoot using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshoot-rdp-connection#troubleshoot-using-the-azure-portal)
- [Troubleshoot Remote Desktop connections to an Azure virtual machine - Troubleshoot VMs created using the Classic deployment model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshoot-rdp-connection#troubleshoot-vms-created-using-the-classic-deployment-model)